# Pass parameter to Celery task's on_failure method

Tags: python, task, celery, scheduled-tasks, django-celery

I'm creating a custom Celery task class in order to override what happens if/when the task reaches the max retries (`on_failure`). I need to update the User model's status if the task fails.

Below is my custom task class:

```
class ReadyTask(Task):

     def run(self, user):
         try:
             user.get_results()
         except Exception as exc:
             raise self.retry(exc=exc, max_retries=3)

     def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, *args, **kwargs):
         user.status = Status.READY
         user.save()
```

How can I pass the User object to the `on_failure()` method to update its status?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can inspect your `args` or `kwargs` for the user's id if you send it into the task as you call it, as a parameter. Easier if you make it in the kwargs so you don't have to do arg position checking. Then just grab your user from the id and make the change?

Thus, do not send it into the `run` function but instead as an argument/keyword-argument to the function that is the task you are calling, via `function.apply(kwargs)`, or `function.apply_async(kwargs=kwargs)` or `function.delay(kwargs)`.

So:

`user_id = kwargs.get('user_id')`

`# then resolve to user object, then update object`

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind objects to your custom task class. By using `bind=True`.

```
class ReadyTask(Task):

     def run(self, user):

         self.user_object = user

         try:
             self.user_object.get_results()
         except Exception as exc:
             raise self.retry(exc=exc, max_retries=3)

     def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, *args, **kwargs):
         self.user_object.status = Status.READY 
         self.user_object.save()

@app.task(base=ReadyTask, bind=True)
def do_stuff(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user_object.do_stuff()
```